# Testing ASP.Net 5 UI with a Headless Browser (that works on Windows, Mac, and Linux)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, asp.net-core, headless, dnx, .net-core

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a headless browser to test the UI of an ASP.net 5 application that targets dnxcore50?  Right now I can build an application that you can develop and run on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  However, you can't run the UI tests because they need browser automation solution like Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You will have exactly the same issues as any other web frameworks.

You could potentially use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to do exactly that.

[phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) has a Windows and OSX build. But at the time of this writing, you would need to compile a Linux version yourself.